# Python - Merge two list columns into unique elements values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to merge two columns that looks like list format. I am trying to capture unique values with merging. I tried to run 'set' on the dataframe, but quite there yet.

```
d = {'list1_col1': [[],[],['apples','apples','bananas','oranges'],['kiwi'],[],['green apples']], 
     'list2_col2': [[],['apples','bananas','oranges','oranges','oranges'],[],['mango'],[],[]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

df['combined_list_col'] = df.list1_col1.astype(str).str.cat(df.list2_col2.astype(str), sep='')
df['combined_list_col'] 

print(df['combined_list_col'].tolist()) # not exactly
print('')
print(''.join([j for i in df['combined_list_col'] for j in i])) # not exactly
```

Currently I am getting:

```
0                                                 [][]
1    []['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges', 'oranges', ...
2         ['apples', 'apples', 'bananas', 'oranges'][]
3                                    ['kiwi']['mango']
4                                                 [][]
5                                   ['green apples'][]
```

Looking for Output like this one:

row_id  combined_list_col

```
1       []
2       [apples, bananas, oranges]
3       [apples,bananas, oranges]
4       ['kiwi','mango']
5       []
6       ['green apples']
```

Here is what I tried:

```
print(df['combined_list_col'].tolist()) # not exactly
print('')
print(''.join([j for i in df['combined_list_col'] for j in i])) # not exactly
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain
pd.Series([list(set(chain.from_iterable(t))) for t in zip(*d.values())])
```

Output:

```
0                            []
1    [apples, oranges, bananas]
2    [apples, oranges, bananas]
3                 [mango, kiwi]
4                            []
5                [green apples]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they are list, why not extend them, also unique those values, like:

```
print((df['list1_col1']+df['list2_col2']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).unique()))
```

Output:

```
0                            []
1    [apples, bananas, oranges]
2    [apples, bananas, oranges]
3                 [kiwi, mango]
4                            []
5                [green apples]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few methods you can use:

```
def method1():
    return pd.Series([list(set(chain.from_iterable(t))) for t in zip(*d.values())])

def method1_mend():
    dd = df.to_dict('list')
    return pd.Series([list(set(chain.from_iterable(t))) for t in zip(*dd.values())])

def method2():
    return (df['list1_col1']+df['list2_col2']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).unique())

def method3():
    return df.apply(lambda row: np.unique(row.list1_col1 + row.list2_col2), axis=1)

def method4():
    return df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row.list1_col1 + row.list2_col2).unique(), axis=1)

def method5():
    return (df['list1_col1']+df['list2_col2']).apply(lambda x: np.unique(x))
```

Here is performance of those methods tested on the data provided:

[image]

We can easily see `method1` is blazing fast. But it cheat a bit, as it actually starts from the dictionary rather than the data frame. So I added another method named `method1_mend()`, to includes the conversion time. But it is still the fastest one. But as I have only tested on a very small data frame supplied above, numpy performance on small data sets could easily overshadowed by its overhead. For a big data frame method1 might not be the best way to go.

Basically from the result, we can conclude that generally numpy operations is faster than Series which is faster than DataFrame operations.